# Accessing parameters when adding filter

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, filters

I am trying to change the out put of **wc_get_rating_html** using this filter

```
apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_get_rating_html', $html, $rating, $count);
```

So far this function works and of course doesn't make any changes.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_rating_html', 'change_rating_output');
function change_rating_output($html){
    return $html;
}
```

My question is that how I can access those **$rating** and **$count** parameters inside the function **change_rating_output** so that I can change the $html as I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `add_filter()`, set the *fourth* parameter to `3` (which is the number of parameters accepted by the callback function which in your case is `change_rating_output()`), and then change your `change_rating_output()` function so that it accepts the `$rating` and `$count` parameters:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_rating_html', 'change_rating_output', 10, 3);
function change_rating_output($html, $rating, $count){
    // Now do what you want with $rating and $count
    return $html;
}
```

See http://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/ for further details.